# Cómo procesar una lista de palabras y hallar palíndromos?

Tags: python

Como Crear una lista que contenga palabras, el usuario decide cuando dejar de ingresar palabras Luego debe mostrar cuales son palíndromo?

```
 palabras = []
 cadena = input("ingrese las palabras que desee: ")
 palabras.append(cadena)
 for x in range(cadena):


 if cadena[::-1] == cadena:
     print("es palindromo") 
 else:
    print( "no es palindromo")
```

**tengo esto, que alguien me ayude por favor :(**

Comment: Hola! ¿Y qué problema tiene ese código? En vez de poner ruido en la pregunta, explica qué te falta o qué falla. Puedes [edit]

Comment: Me parece ver una pregunta, pero no estoy seguro. ¿Podrías editar la pregunta y mejorar la redacción para entenderte mejor?

Comment: Mas allá de que el for sobra, solo te falta poner en bucle el código. Por que no lo haces? Que te traba? Hay algo que no sepa que invalida el código actual?

Comment: no se si mi código esta bien, por que igual se ve que me faltan cosas, y lo que no puedo hacer es que no se como hacer para identificar cuales de las palabras ingresadas en la lista son palíndromas

Comment: lo que necesito hacer en este código es que el usuario pueda ingresar las palabras que desee y las palabras las tengo que almacenar en una lista y después de ahí tengo que mostrar en pantalla cuales de todas las palabras ingresadas son palíndromas, ya tengo el código para identificar cual es palíndroma pero lo que no puedo es como sacarlas una por una y verificar cual es palíndroma, espero puedan ayudarme, no se si se entendió ;(

Comment: Agrega a la lista la palabra SOLO si es palindroma. Es decir, si el if da verdadero. El input y la validacion ponlo en un bucle while para que continue hasta que la variable donde guardas lo almacenado por el usuario (inicializala con otro valor antes) sea, por ejemplo, fin. Luego del while, hacé un print de la lista. Y listo c:

Comment: Por cierto, en realidad, no deberia estar guiandote. En este sitio no damos guias y orientaciones, ya que no encajan con el formato de este (como te doy una respuesta?) Recomiendo que recurras a otro sitio u otra formacde ayuda o ganes akgo de reputacion y entres a nuestro chat.

Comment: okey muchas gracias

Comment: De nada Oscar c: